# Eclipse C++ Debug Session terminates with error <terminated, exit value: -1073741819>gdb (8.1)

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, mingw-w64

When I click on "memory view" for any variable declared in my program, Eclipse CDT debug session suddenly terminates with error - "terminated, exit value: -1073741819" gdb (8.1)
Debugging otherwise (without clicking on memory view) seems to work fine.
I am using MinGW-w64 with gdb version 8.1 and Eclipse package release date is 09/2019.
Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you solve it?

Comment: Though I wasnt able to resolve this issue, I found a workaround, by using Cgywin complier and associated gdb in Eclipse CDT as this issue seemed specific to gdb debugger for MinGW.